# CKEditor Cache problem, edit skin css

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm trying to edit the dialog.css for a skin on CKEditor, the problem is it seems to be caching the css and no matter what, it doesn't seem to clear.  I've switched browsers, cleared all cache, I also have the CKEDITOR.timesampe line uncommented from ckeditor_source.js, but still the CSS doesn't update.

Any ideas how to clear cache on this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you definitely editing the correct dialog.css - i.e. the one in your chosen skins folder?

Comment: @Barry - Yeah, in fact it's adding ?t=B8DJ5M3 to the end of the dialog.css file.  If I remove that, it shows my version but with it, it shows an older version, so somewhere its being cached.

Comment: I have this same problem every time I try to edit a CKEditor style. The cache usually clears eventually, but it's super annoying. Have you had any success figuring this out?

Answer (score -1):

There's a `timestamp` parameter in the file `ckeditor.js`.

You can change its value to reset cache